# Chart control is it possible to position the horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: c#, charts

I have a chart with a Y axis of 0 to 1 and X axis in date time. I also have the horizontal scrollbar enabled on zoom. My problem is that, the data points which have a value of 0 are being clipped with the scrollbar.  So can I move it a few pixels below the chart or move the Y axis slighty?

Regards.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot position the scrollbar directly.

But you can **either** move the scrollbar out of the innerplot area:

```
yourXAxis.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = false;
```

**or** move the x-axis (!) a little up:

```
Axis ay = yourChartArea.AxisY;

ay.Interval = 2;                  // pick your interval!
ay.Minimum = -0.75f;              // pick a value that works for you
ay.IntervalOffset = -ay.Minimum;  // adapt the interval
```

Note that this is not in pixels but in data values of the Axis! You **could** convert pixels <-> values in the `PrePaint` or `PostPaint`  event using the `PixelPositionToValue` and `ValueToPixelPosition` functions.

Below are the results: Before, after `IsPositionedInside = false` and after moving the x-axis:

[image]
[image]
[image]